# Javascript promise object didn't work async with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I've an promise object that result from sequelize findAll, I tried to loop the data using `map` but it doesn't work like I need. Here the example of my code:

```
const list = await queueProcess.findAll({
    where: {
        id: {[Op.between]: [start, end]},
        is_active: true
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'param_value']
});

await Promise.all(
    list.map(async (e) => {
        console.log("Promise");
        const check = await checkProcess(e.id);
   })
)
```

this is another function from another file:

```
checkProcess: async (id) =>{
    console.log("Check");
}
```

it give me result:

```
Promise
Promise
Check
Check
```

and what I need is

```
Promise
Check
Promise
Check
```

Why does this happen? I thought that my code is appropriate, and can work asyncly.

Comment: The asynchronous processes run in parallell but you want to run them in sequence. To accomplish that, use a `for` or `while` loop instead of `map()` and `await` each process. That way each process will resolve before the next one is initiated.

Answer (score 1):

Each `.map` callback is running immediately, in parallel - each item in the `list` results in `Promise` being logged, and separately, `checkProcess` is called for each. The Promises here are not intrinsically connected to each other (not until they resolve, after which the `Promise.all` recognizes it and resolves itself).

If you want every iteration to fully resolve before the next iteration starts, use a `for` loop for serial processing instead of `Promise.all`, which is for parallel processing:

```
for (const e of list) {
  console.log('Promise');
  const check = await checkProcess(e.id);
}
```

Comment: This isn't an async iterable, it's just an iterable, so `for await` isn't really appropriate, it's just syntax noise.

Comment: I've tried this and it's not working for mine, I think I should add my complete code, because I'm using `fs`.

Comment: Feel free to add your complete code whenever you want